# ConvertTo-Json formatting output

Tags: powershell

Please help me if you can.
i am using powershell get-aduser command to extract user info

```
$adusers = @( "Name","SamAccountName","GivenName","Surname","UserAccountControl","WhenCreated","lastLogonDate")

$users = get-aduser -filter * -Properties $aduser
```

then i write this to a file

```
$users | select $adusers | convertto-json | out-file "test.JSON"
```

the output i got "/Date(1568702005000)/" ....

strangely i got 2 different server, only 1 server does this, any idea ?

Comment: Can you share the output of `$users | Select-Object $adusers | ConvertTo-Json`?

Comment: @AdminOfThings That was my first thought too, but the datetime objects shouldn't be formatted that way when `ToString()`'d. I'm not aware of any localization that would. When I run `@{ Time = [DateTime]::Now } | ConvertTo-Json` outputs `2021-09-01T14:30:47.2576307-05:00` (my time of execution and localization) for the time field in the JSON string. This is why I wanted to see the the JSON content itself (sanitized of course) to better understand the current output.

Comment: using Select-Object $adusers date look like this

        "WhenCreated":  "\/Date(1537924203000)\/",
        "lastLogonDate":  "\/Date(1630257065410)\/",

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't explain this; this looks like an actual *JavaScript* `Date` constructor that renders to `Tue Sep 25 2018 20:10:03 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)` for `Date(1568702005000)`. I have no idea why `Get-ADUser` would return it like this.

Comment: i did few verification, Get-ADUser output is fine when goes to csv, the moment I start to use convertto-json, the date start to mess around.

funny thing is the same script run on different machine and only 1 work fine but not others. ps version and other component are same version, i cant figure out why the convertto-json only working on 1 machine

Comment: Does this also happen if you use property `Created` instead of `whenCreated`? (`Created` is the LDAP whenCreated property converted to local DateTime object)

Comment: If you set the format yourself both machines should do the same when using ConvertTo-Json, maybe something like `$users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties Created, LastLogonDate, userAccountControl |  Select-Object Name, SamAccountName, GivenName, Surname, UserAccountControl, @{Name = 'WhenCreated'; Expression = {$_.Created.ToString("o")}},  @{Name = 'LastLogon'; Expression = {$_.LastLogonDate.ToString("o")}}`. --> ISO 8601 format. Properties `Name, SamAccountName, GivenName, Surname` are returned by default, soyou don't need to ask for these.

Comment: thanks guys, i found the root cause. 1 machine i am having powershell 7 and convertto-json and gave me time properly. 2001-03-22T21:32:12+08:00

in another machine which doesnt has power7 install, which is running powershell5 and giving me "/Date(1568702005000)/"

Comment: You say $aduser instead of $adusers in line 2.  If it's any consolation, convertfrom-json will covert it back to a datetime in powershell 5.1.